# how to implement custom verification mail link functionality with aws lamda and ses?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I am following the bellow link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendCustomVerificationEmail.html

Comment: You probably want to add a few more details on the question here, like what language you are using? and where you have got stuck in trying to implement this?

Comment: you are asking about configuration or usage of lamda and ses?

Comment: can you share little bit of your progress
You can probably check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786384/how-to-call-a-list-of-aws-lambda-permissions-for-a-function?rq=1

Comment: I am using nodejs, i have a userpool , i am attaching pre signup lamda trigger . i have to verify user through phone no and as well as email flag.ses functionality cognito it self handling.  when only email or phone verification then i am getting the mail and code, but i have validate both phone no and email . i am using event.response.autoConfirmEmail = true; @JamesKn

Comment: I want to know how to use lamda trigger and cognito @debaonline4u